# svn: E155010: The node was not found

Tags: svn, copy

I have the below script working fine without any issues. This script copies whole current directory and creates a tag.

```
if($tag) 
{
    $directory = $directory.replace('''','')
    if ($directory.Substring($directory.length-1,1) -ne "/")
    {
        $directory += "/"
    }
    $directory += $label + "/"
    $svnComment = "Tagging Release v - " + $label

    Write-Host "Creating tag @ " $directory
    svn copy . $directory --username ADMIN --message $svnComment --trust-server-cert --non-interactive
}
```

After the build is executed, bin directory is created. I am trying to copy only the contents of bin folder to create a tag. But ending with this below error svn: E155010: The node 'D:\BuildServer\FolderA\bin\Release\####.dll' was not found.
Actually, that particular dll is present in the bin directory.
My changed script to copy bin folder to create tag is below:

```
if($tag) 
{
    $directory = $directory.replace('''','')
    if ($directory.Substring($directory.length-1,1) -ne "/")
    {
        $directory += "/"
    }
    $directory += $label + "/"
    $svnComment = "Tagging Release v - " + $label

    Write-Host "Creating tag @ " $directory
    svn copy bin\Release\* $directory --username ADMIN --message $svnComment --trust-server-cert --non-interactive
}
```

This is so frustrating.